# Android EditText hint above text?

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint, android-textinputedittext

How can I create an android EditText, where the hint goes above the text when you tap inside and start typing?
[image]

Comment: Check this: [TextInputLayout](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android)

Answer (score 1):

Use "TextInputLayout" & "TextInputEditText"

for example

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:hint="Your Header here">


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```